# Static includes in nested namespaces using Mako

Tags: pyramid, mako

I'm trying [this method](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/namespaces.html#version-two-use-a-specific-named-def) to add static includes to my namespaces but I'm facing the problem that, static includes from nested namespaces are not included in the base template. To make the problem more concrete, below I post some example code:

**base.mako**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    % for ns in context.namespaces.values():
        % if hasattr(ns, 'includes'):
    ${ns.includes()}
        % endif
    % endfor
</head>
<body>
    ${next.body()}
</body>
</html>
```

**child.mako**

```
<%inherit file="base.mako"/>
<%namespace name="rb" file="buttons.mako"/>
${rb.render_buttons}
```

**buttons.mako**

```
<%namespace name="lib" file="lib.mako"/>

<%def name="includes()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.static_url('project:static/lib.js')}"></script>
</%def>
<%def name="render_buttons()>
    <button onclick="some_function_from_lib_js()">Click me!</button>
    ${lib.render_text()}
</%def>
```

**lib.mako**

```
<%def name="includes()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="${request.static_url('project:static/other.js')}"></script>
</%def>
<%def name="render_text()">
    <button onclick="some_function_from_other_js()">No! Click me!</button>
</%def>
```

This is just an example but I hope it suffices to describe my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in the code you posted. Also, there are references to external (`request` for example) entities. Please always make sure your code is correct and works before posting.

The problem seems to be that `context.namespaces` is collection of namespaces declared **only** in templates in inheritance chain. This could be inferred from the following [statement](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/namespaces.html#namespace-api-usage-example-static-dependencies) from docs:

> Iterating the values of this dictionary will provide a `Namespace`
>   object for each time the `<%namespace>` tag was used, anywhere within
>   the inheritance chain.

Your inheritance chain consists from child.mako and base.mako only. Out of these only child.mako declares namespace (`rb`) and thus this is the only namespace in `context.namespaces`. You can see this easily if you insert `${ns.uri}` after `% for ns in context.namespaces.values():` line. This will render `buttons.mako` string alone in the output.

The solution in your case would be to look for `includes` defs not only in namespaces declared in templates in inheritance chain but also in namespaces declared by those namespaces. Something like

```
% for ns in context.namespaces.values():
    % for ns2 in ns.context.namespaces.values():
        % if hasattr(ns2, 'includes'):
            ${ns2.includes()}
        % endif
    % endfor
    % if hasattr(ns, 'includes'):
        ${ns.includes()}
    % endif
% endfor
```

However it does not work from what I see and don't know why.

Comment: Yes, I had tried the code you posted, but it seems like `ns.context.namespaces` gives the same namespaces as `context.namespaces.values`.